# How to put multiple Id Parameter in @URL. Action And the Controller Fetches the ID

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a View that is like this

```
<td><a href="@Url.Action("AddingAnnouncement", new { id = item.ScheduleID,name =item.EmployeeID})" class="btn btn-warning"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i> Adding Announcement</a></td>
```

the Fetching the id part i get it but the name part i can't get the name part for the controller when i go to that link it passes the id and name yes but the controller cannot get the Name id or the value of name how can i get that as well ?

This is my Controller

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Faculty")]
public ActionResult AddingAnnouncement(int? name)
{

    return View (name);

}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddingAnnouncement(int? id,int? name, Announcement model, HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    Announcement annc = new Announcement();
    var ErrorMessage = "";
    var filesize = 25000;
    foreach (var item in model.File)
    {
        try
        {
            var supportedTypes = new[] { "txt", "doc", "docx", "pdf", "xls", "xlsx" };
            var fileExt = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(file.FileName).Substring(1);
            if (!supportedTypes.Contains(fileExt))
            {
                ErrorMessage = "File Extension Is InValid - Only Upload WORD/PDF/EXCEL/TXT File";
                return Content(ErrorMessage);
            }
            else if (file.ContentLength > (filesize * 1024))
            {
                ErrorMessage = "File size Should Be UpTo " + filesize + "KB";
                return Content(ErrorMessage);
            }

            else
            {
                annc.MainAnnouncement = model.MainAnnouncement;
                annc.EmployeeID = name;
                annc.DatePosted = DateTime.Now;
                annc.ScheduleID = id;
                annc.DocumentFile = ConverToByte(item);
                annc.FileType = file.ContentType;
                annc.FileName = file.FileName;
                db.Announcements.Add(annc);
                string path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Files/TeachingMaterials/"), Path.GetFileName(file.FileName));
                file.SaveAs(path);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ErrorMessage = "Upload Container Should Not Be Empty or Contact Admin";
            return Content(ErrorMessage);
        }



    }
    return RedirectToAction("FacultySchedule");
}
```

Comment: If i do not put the name parameter in get it does not fetch the value of name in the post part any ideas how to fetch it ?

Answer (score 0):

NVm found it damn i never thought it is that simple i haha XD

on the get controller

```
    [Authorize(Roles = "Faculty")]
    public ActionResult AddingAnnouncement(int? name)
    {
        Announcement model = new Announcement();
        model.EmployeeID = name;
        return View(model);

    }
```

then on the post

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddingAnnouncement(int? id,Announcement model,    HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
    }
```